# No 'Add New Item' of type Report or Report Wizard in my VS2013 Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, rdlc

Going bananas with this, i'm using Visual Studio 2013 and now at the stage of adding RDLC reports via a web form and iFrame

However I cannot find anything out there on why I have no 'Add New Item' of type Report. Am I missing a NuGet package or something?

Only thing I added via Nuget So far is Install-Package Microsoft.Report.Viewer

Cheers, J

Comment: Perhaps I need to install SSDT or something, anyone think this is it? If so is their a latest download for Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat unbelievable but as of now this scenario is still not supported.  You will need to go back to VS2012, or wait.

Please add your vote and furious comment here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/806079/ssdt-bi-add-visual-studio-2013-support-to-sql-server-data-tools-for-business-intelligence